# Getting the value of a variable from another script in fish shell

Tags: shell, fish

I have two scripts in the same directory:

`latlong.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
set latlong 'x.xxxxxx:x.xxxxxx'
```

`autostart_once.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
. ./latlong.sh
# some start up commands
redshift-gtk -l $latlong -t 6500:3600 &
```

However, running `autostart_once.sh` above will yield an error. It seems like even after sourcing the latlong script the `latlong` variable is still empty (I have made sure the working directory is where latlong.sh is). However if I run `. ./latlong.sh` in a terminal running a fish shell and then `echo $latlong` the variable is set correctly. What could be happening here?

A few things:

1. I don't want to be able to access the variable outside the autostart script.
2. The reason why I am putting the latlong variable to another file is that I encrypt that file before pushing it to a dotfiles repository, but I do not want to encrypt the startup file so that other people can use it as well.

Comment: The shebang for `autostart_once.sh` is #!/bin/sh, so it will run it with that shell instead of fish. Did you mean to set it to fish?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish I have changed the shebang line to be #!/usr/bin/env fish and the same problem persists.

Comment: ah I fixed it. It was a typo

Answer (score 2):

The `.` in `. ./latlong.sh` is also known as `source` in some shells. [0]

What it does is tell the current shell to run the given script in the current shell.

That means this in a /bin/sh script will run `latlong.sh` *with /bin/sh*, no matter the shebang, and so it will run

```
set latlong 'x.xxxxxx:x.xxxxxx'
```

which will set the positional arguments to `latlong` and `x.xxxxxx:x.xxxxxx`. It's syntactically valid but means something entirely different in /bin/sh from what it means in fish. And when you run `. ./latlong.sh` in fish, that fish will read it and interpret `set` as the fish builtin.

In short: Your simplest solution here is to write both scripts in the same language. This will allow you to `source` them in the same shell, keeping the variables intact.

If your latlong.sh is as trivial as the example you've shown here, that's easy:

```
latlong=x.xxxxxx:x.xxxxxx
```

Or you could choose a data format like csv or json or whathaveyou and find ways to load *that* into whatever shell.

Or you could attempt the same thing [direnv](https://direnv.net/) does, which is run the script in a defined shell (bash in their case) and then [diff the environment variables](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/blob/master/internal/cmd/env_diff.go) to apply them in the user's shell.

[0]: sadly this isn't required by posix and so we're often stuck with the unreadable and easy to miss `.` name